# Installing GSL in R (two versions?)

Tags: r, linux, centos, gsl

Trying to figure out how to get a new version of gsl recognized by R. I added the last two lines to the Makevars file because I couldn't get the system to recognize this new version as default.

```
CXX14FLAGS=-O3 -march=native -mtune=native -fPIC
CXX14=g++ -std=c++14
CXX_STD=CXX14
GSL_CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/gsl/2.4/include
GSL_LIBGS=-L/usr/local/gsl/2.4/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

However, when I go to install, you can see part of it is calling 2.4 and part isn't.

[image]

Note that according to gsl's github page, the error I'm getting is consistent with a 1.X version of gsl.

Any help (1) getting centos to recognize the new gsl version or (2) just getting R to use it to compile the gsl package would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why keep gsl-devel-1.15 ?? ... Suggest `# yum remove gsl-devel`

Comment: Okay, now system("gsl-config --version") returns 2.4. However (even after updating Makevars), now R errors with "error: Need GSL version >= 1.16".

Comment: I was able to fix this issue by specifying LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/gsl/2.4/lib/ in my .bash_profile.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that gsl 2.5>= is needed. The error message is not updated, see

https://github.com/RobinHankin/gsl/issues/18